# Gradle does not allow my app to connect to mysql server

Tags: android, mysql, unity-game-engine, gradle

So some background info :

-My mysql server is hosted on a dedicated website

-When I build the project in Unity as internal everything works fine and connects correctly but the graphics in the background seem a bit jarring.

-When I build my project with gradle I am able to connect to the mysql server in the unity play window but when I build the project to my android phone, it is unable to connect to the mysql server

-I do have the internet access setting in the build settings set to required so that is not the issue.

So is there anything or any setting that allows gradle to connect to the internet when building to an android device or am I missing something. Thanks!